# Matlab: trasform to cell of strings

Tags: string, matlab, cell

Problem: I have postfix (137x25) cell that contain cell of char (Ex postfix(6,8)=postfix{6,8}{1,1}<1x3char>). I want to trasform it in (137x25) cell of char.

Postfix is created in this way:

```
for l=1:25
    [matches(:,l), postfix(:,l)] = regexp(semanticTrajCompact(1,4).TrajCompact,sprintf('%d%d(.*)',digits{1}(l),digits{2}(l)),'match','once','tokens');
end
```

I have tried different solutions:

Solution 1

```
numIndex = cellfun('isclass', postfix, 'double');
  tmpStr = sprintf('%g;', postfix{numIndex});
  postfix(numIndex) = dataread('string', tmpStr, '%s', 'delimiter', ';');
```

Solution 2

```
postfix(cellfun(@isempty,postfix))={''};
```

Solution 3

```
postfix(cellfun(@isnumeric, postfix)) =  cellfun(@(x) sprintf('%.5f', x), postfix(cellfun(@isnumeric, postfix)), 'UniformOutput', false)
```

Solution 4

I try to use

```
char(postix)
```

Anyone of this solution trasform postfix in a (137x25 array of char). Can you give me other ideas?

Comment: can you give a small example (use something like a 2 x 2 cell Array) of what your original cells look like and what you want your result to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to loop over every element of the cell array postfix, and replace each element of the cell array (which is a cell array itself) by its contents. Using `cellfun` to replace the loop, you therefore write:

```
postfix = cellfun(@(x)x{1}, postfix, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem also in this way

```
for k=1:25
    for j=size(postfix,1)
        if(~isempty(postfix{j,k}))
            postfix{j,k}=char(postfix{j,k}{1,1});
        end
    end
end

postfix(cellfun(@isempty,postfix))={''};
```